# I am able to return value of a string type when the function return type is Promise<any> when using Async

Tags: angular, typescript

I was creating a custom pipe when I came across this. Why is the example below valid?

```
async transform(value: any): Promise<string> {
    let fullNameBasedOnPreference: string;

    fullNameBasedOnPreference = value.property;

    return fullNameBasedOnPreference;
  }
```

Link for reference: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-iphhv3?file=src/app/my-pipe.pipe.ts

Comment: Because you're using `any`. Don't use `any` unless you want to give up on type-checking.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thank you. I tried that but thats not it.

Comment: Pretty sure it is it. What were you expecting instead?

Comment: Because of `async`. The compiler transforms your function into a "state-machine" around `await` calls and `returns` actually resolves the promise implicitly returned. If you look at the compiled Javascript you'll see what's actually done. All compiler eye-candy for the sake of simulating syncronous programing in what's really an `async` call.

Comment: @Alejandro Thank you for your response. But thats not what I was looking for. The return type of my function is `Promise<string>` and I am returning a `string` type which should have given a type mismatch error. That was my dilemma.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I was expecting an error. Removing the `async` from the function gives `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Promise<string>'` error.

Comment: @shix The error isn't there just because of the `async`. Async functions return `Promise<T>` (where T can be any type, string here), but in their bodies, the `return` instruction actually returns a T, not a Promise. It's the compiler that does the magic and adds the Promise and wraps your code within it, as the accepted answer shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you are referring to the fact you can return string as any, or why you can return a string when the return type is `Promise<any>`. I.E. Your question would be the same if the return type was Promise.

Assuming the later: the async modifier will cause the return value to be wrapped by the Typescript compiler as a promise*.

*It's probably more complicated than this under the hood, but that's the gist of it.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/what-about-async-await/

Comment: I was asking the later as mentioned in the title. So, in this case async will wrap the whole function including the return value. Thank you, that helped. Follow up question: is this a good practice or is this practiced in general? Since I have already declared the return type as promise.

Comment: Yes, it is practiced in general. It's symanic sugar for creating promises. Your code looks fine, except I would change the return type to Promise<string> if you are only going to be returning a string... Although, you probably don't benefit at all making this function async (a promise) since it doesn't have to wait for anything and isn't long running.

Answer (score 0):

You are giving the `any` type to your `value` variable. In fact your telling typescript that all types apply to your `value`. So typescript will assume that `value.property` is a `string` value as it could be for example:

```
const value = {
    property: 'string'
}
```

That's why it works fine.
I would suggest not using any if you know the structure of your variable. Changes are that a custom type has already been defined that you can reuse. If not, create an `Interface` describing the type of your data and import it in your component/service.

Comment: Thank you for getting back. Thats not the issue here. The issue is that I am returning `fullNameBasedOnPreference` which is declared with type of string while my function `transform` return datatype for the function is `Promise<string>`. My question was why is this not throwing an error. I am satisfied with Ray's answer above.
Btw, I am using this function as a pipe and accepting objects from different models. I have modified the middle part of the function.

Comment: Because when a function is of type Promise<string> it expects a to be returned a string... If you are satisfied with an answer, mark it as accepted, so we do not lose time answering more.

Comment: I am currently looking for implementation details of the `__awaiter` function which is mentioned in the link Ray has mentioned. I will mark the answer as soon as I am done.